# Java try catch issue

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

all I am trying to accomplish with this code is to check the users' input is that of an integer, and then to give them 3 chances at inputting it again if it wasn't the correct data type. And then finally throwing an exception if they reach the "maxTries" mark.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Cheers.

```
    boolean correctInput = false;    
    int returnedInt = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int maxTries = 3;

    Scanner kybd = new Scanner(System.in); 

    while(!correctInput)
    {
        try 
        {   
            System.out.println("\nInput your int, you have had:" + count + " tries");
            returnedInt = kybd.nextInt();
            correctInput = true;

        }
        catch(InputMismatchException e)
        {
            System.out.println("That is not an integer, please try again..");   
            if (++count == maxTries) throw e;

        }

    }
    return returnedInt;
```

Comment: What is the problem you're having with this code? Error messages? Does it not do what it's supposed to, and if so, what does it do instead?

Comment: I think you're not setting correctInput to false so it jumps out of the loop

Comment: String
That is not an integer, please try again..

Input your int, you have had:1 tries
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
That is not an integer, please try again..

Input your int, you have had:2 tries
That is not an integer, please try again..
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:909)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2160)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119)
 at Main.inputInt(Main.java:25)
 at Main.main(Main.java:10)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 5 seconds)

Comment: So essentially it runs through the loop on it's own.

Comment: and doesn't ask for input the 3rd and 2nd time.

Answer (score 2):

The reason this is happening is because your Scanner's buffer is not cleared. The input `kybd.nextInt()` is already filled with a non-int, but since it failed at reading it, it hasn't actually gotten rid of it off the stack. So the second loop it attempts to pull the filled buffer, which was already wrong, again.

To fix this, you can clear the buffer by using `nextLine()` in your exception handling.

```
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out
                    .println("That is not an integer, please try again..");
            kybd.nextLine(); //clear the buffer, you can System.out.println this to see that the stuff you typed is still there
            if (++count == maxTries)
                throw e;

        }
```

The other alternative is to use `String s = kybd.nextLine()` and parse for Integer and catch the exception from that instead.

Comment: I'm fine with taking a ding for a -1, but it would help me for you to explain why it deserved a -1.

Comment: To verify this, add a line in your catch clause:     System.out.println("input was: " +kybd.next());`-- you'll see that the faulty input is still in the queue. Ironically, this will clear up the problem... :)

Comment: Sorry about the ding, it was a slip of the trackpad, and SO won't let me reverse it - but if you make some trivial edit, apparently then I'll be able to change my vote.

Comment: @JonKiparsky Silly human-input devices :P Thanks, I'll do some non-trivial edits.